# Software to plot a log graph

Tags: data-visualization, logarithm

I have to plot a graph with log distribution on y axis.  The values are: 10^-3..10^3.

What software do you suggest me to use.

My OS is Ubuntu, so I prefer software for Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are using LaTeX for your report writing, the package pgfplots can read in data files and plot single or double logarithmic axis. In case you need to do calculations you can escape to gnuplot.

It just looks this tiny bit better if your text font matches your axis labels font.

Comment: Indeed I use LaTeX. Also your approach avoids the pain of creating EPSs and importing them.

Answer (score 9):

R is good and can be freely downloaded from http://www.r-project.org/

R takes some time to get used to, but here's a simple example ("#" indicates that a comment follows):

```
x <- rnorm(20)  # generate a sample of size 20 from N(0,1)
y <- 10^x  # define y_i = 10^(x_i) for each i=1,...,20
plot(x, y)  # plot y vs x
plot(x, y, log="y")  # plot y vs x with log scale for y
```

Edited after comment from @chl

Comment: Please, give an example of use for semi-log plot in R to make your answer complete and acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use the open source plotting package [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for this task. The first section of a very readable tutorial [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot6-e.html) shows how to plot with a log scale.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and easy graph, you should give [GraphCalc](http://graphcalc.com) a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [DMelt](http://jwork.org/dmelt) software environment written in Java
  Most examples use Python scripting. Look at the class HPlot. It has a support for log scale on X and Y